# INSERT INTO SELECT - shrink 2 columns in one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to shrink two columns - `note` and `app` from `dbo.UCAST3$` - into column `klient.appendix`

This is how I try to shrink 2 columns with small note:  `[note] + ' appendix: ' + [app]`

I tried following:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.klient
  (name, surname, rodcis, nopass, street, zip, city, appendix, tel, fax, titul, akce, rocnik)
  SELECT 
     [nameorig], [surnameorig], [rodcisorig], [nopassorig], [adresa], [ZIP], [place],
     [note] + ' appendix: ' + [app], [telhome], [telwork], titul, '000000-00', 2014 
  FROM dbo.UCAST3$
```

I get following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

It seems that it is skipping to next column `nopassorig` which is numeric.

Can anyone please help me solve this out?

- `[note]` is `decimal(30,0)`
- `[app]` is `nvarchar(255)`

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine and the datatypes of the three columns.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help: `[note] is decimal(30,0) [app] is nvarchar(255)`and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast [note] as varchar to successfully concatenate.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.klient
(name, surname,rodcis,nopass,street,zip,city,appendix,tel,fax,titul,akce,rocnik)
SELECT [nameorig], [surnameorig],[rodcisorig],
       [nopassorig],[adresa],[ZIP],[place],
       CAST([note] as VARCHAR(30)) + ' appendix: ' + [app],
       [telhome],[telwork],titul,'000000-00',2014
 FROM dbo.UCAST3$
```

Comment: @marc_s no marc sir i don't know the default length in CASE statement , in data definition it is 1 and in CAST and convert functions it is 30.

Answer (score 3):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Please don't do it. If you ever want to seperate the values again in SQL this will be a pain and slow.

Just concatete the values in the SQL select statments where you need it.